# save PowerShell command in variable and execute in cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to save a PowerSell command in a variable and execute in a cmd
Problem :  get current path with exe file using command : $(get-location).Path

I try this but not working :

```
Set $path = powershell -Command $(get-location).Path
echo "$path"
```

Comment: This code does not work in `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`. I would recommend not starting environment variable names with a DOLLAR SIGN ($) character. Yes, it can work, but it might lead to confustion. Also, `PATH` is a well defined system variable that should generally not be redefined. Certainly not as anything other than the execution search path.

Comment: In `cmd.exe`, use `SET "MY_VAR=value"`. Note the use and placement of QUOTATION MARK characters. However, for this question, it is better to use the value in a `FOR` loop. Do not put a SPACE character before the EQUALS SIGN character. If it is done, the variable `MY_VAR ` will be created. Note the SPACE character at the end of the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for similar command line, Note we need to escape the first ) using `^)`

```
C:\Users\K\Desktop>for /f "delims=" %c in ('powershell -Command $(get-location^).Path') do @set "$path=%c"

C:\Users\K\Desktop>echo %$path%
C:\Users\K\Desktop

C:\Users\K\Desktop>
```

so in a batch file use

```
for /f "delims=" %%c in ('powershell -Command $(get-location^).Path') do @set "$path=%%c"
echo %$path%
```

However there are many much simpler ways to find the current directory.

As suggested avoid any variable name that is very similar to "path" such as $path since it may be misunderstood by a downstream app stripping $, but the simplest way at cmd level would be to use the %cd% value:-

```
C:\Users\K\Desktop>set "ExDir=%cd%" & echo %ExDir%
C:\Users\K\Desktop

C:\Users\K\Desktop>
```

In a batch file it is common to use pushd and popd with a stored %~dp0 however at command line popd may not have a directory stack to return to, thus this method can be used.

```
C:\Users\K\Desktop>set "PopDir=%cd%"

C:\Users\K\Desktop>cd /d h:

H:\>echo doing somthing in %cd%
doing somthing in H:\

H:\>cd /D "%PopDir%"

C:\Users\K\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way without Invoke-Expression but with two variables (command:string and parameters:array). It works fine for me. Assume 7z.exe is in the system path.

```
$cmd = '7z.exe'
$prm = 'a', '-tzip', 'c:\temp\with space\test1.zip', 'C:\TEMP\with space\changelog'

& $cmd $prm
```

If the command is known (7z.exe) and only parameters are variable then this will do

```
$prm = 'a', '-tzip', 'c:\temp\with space\test1.zip', 'C:\TEMP\with space\changelog'

& 7z.exe $prm
```

BTW, Invoke-Expression with one parameter works for me, too, e.g. this works

```
$cmd = '& 7z.exe a -tzip "c:\temp\with space\test2.zip" "C:\TEMP\with space\changelog"'

Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

P.S. I usually prefer the way with a parameter array because it is easier to compose programmatically than to build an expression for Invoke-Expression.

Comment: I won't execute a parameter , First , I want to store PowerShell in a variable and do echo in cmd   , thanks